# How to check browser sessions exists or not when there are two instances of browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have to verify whether browser session exists in after Each function for teach down code when there are two instances of browsers are running .If suppose there is a closing  of one browser, I have to  add tear down app specific logic of the app by checking with the browser session .

Answer (score 0):

To verify browser session, check if your app stores any session specific cookies that identifies the user. If yes, then just see if that cookie exists using [getCookie](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.getCookie) function -

```
browser.manage().getCookie('your_session_cookie_name').then(function(appCookie){
    if (appCookie === null) console.log('session doesnt exist');
    else console.log('session exists');
});
```

You can [get all cookies](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.getCookies) in the form of an array from browser and see if your app cookie exists. Here's how -

```
browser.manage().getCookies().then(function(allCookies){
    console.log(allCookies);
    //allCookies is an array, verify if your cookie is present in it
});
```

In order to verify if the session is related to an instance of browser, then perform the above operations when the required browser's instance in focus for protractor.

Hope it helps.